# addHeaderView в ListView изменяет количество элементов списка

Tags: java, android

Добавляю `addHeaderView` в `ListView`:

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
   super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
   setList();
}

private void setList()
{
    try
    {
        mListView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview);
        mListView = getListView();
       setListAdapter(new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.listview, itemname, imgid));
       LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
       View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_header, mListView, false);
       getListView().addHeaderView(header, null, false);

     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.e(LOG_TAG, ex.getMessage());
     }
}
```

И получается что когда `addHeaderView` добавилось, то по `ListView` идет смещение на 1 позицию! Тоесть `addHeaderView` становится `ITEM 0` и после него идет уже сам `ListView` по порядку... Как это исправить?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [В доках](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView(android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean)) написано, что до Android 4.4 добавлять хэдер надо **ДО** назначения адаптера к списку.
2. Если под

   > идет смещение на 1 позицию

   вы имеете в виду, что запрашивая данные по позиции в списке вы получаете не те данные, то просто переопределите в адаптере методы, возвращающие данные по позиции так, чтобы они возвращали данные по **position-1**

Comment: чет я туплю! это как? 0_о

Comment: Ну, например, если вы в адаптере получаете какие-либо данные по позиции **getData(int position)**, то возвращать из него надо не **data.get(position)**, а **data.get(position-1)**. Также можно и со всякими clickListener поступать.

Answer (score 1):

1. Добавлять вызывать `addHeaderView` & `addFooterView` необходимо до того как вызовешь метод `setAdapter`. В `API 19 >=` можно вызывать в любой момент.
2. В методе `OnItemClickListener.onItemClick` вызови `parent.getAdapter().getItem(position)`, он вернет тебе правильный объект.

При вызове методов `ListView.addHeaderView()` или `ListView.addFooterView()` твой `Adapter` автоматически обернут в `HeaderViewListAdapter`.

[ListView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/ListView.java)

[HeaderVIewListAdapter](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/widget/HeaderViewListAdapter.java)

Comment: я использую public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) { и свитчу все что мне надо!

Comment: просто в дальнейшем хочу сделать 2 адаптера, listView и GridView

Comment: Все будет работать, GridView и ListView наследники AdapterView.